# Regular expression for only allow numbers and must end with single '#' sign at end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Hi i want to validate a string with in which only numbers are allowed and only one # sign at

the end.I use this but it allow double # sign at end.

```
    /^[0-9]+#/
```

How i can refine it to only allow single # sign at end of string like 1345#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `^` and `$`. Use `\A` and `\z` instead! It's a big gotcha!

```
/\A[0-9]+#\z/
```

`^` and `$` are used to specify the **end of the LINE**, not sting!

```
# don't do this!!!
/^[0-9]+\#$/ =~ "12#\nfoo" # MATCHES!!!
```

I hope it'll help someone else!

Comment: i didn't know about this ruby-specific behaviour... http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

Answer (score 2):

use `$` for matching the end of string

```
/^[0-9]+#$/
```

Comment: You've got a pitfall! See my answer. Also `#` before `$` has to be escaped.

Comment: it seems mine is a regex answer, not a ruby one :)